# Gentoo: How to update from one portage only?

Tags: gentoo, emerge

I have an overlay alone with the default portage. Basically, I want to emerge only the updates from the main portage when I run **emerge world -unD**, and emerge the extra packages from the overlay explicitly.

But now, each time I run **emerge world**, I got all the packages from both portage.

I want to know what is the best way to keep enforce update from one portage only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should edit it in files /etc/portage/*
In /etc/portage/provided/package.provided
you place files which you do not want to be updated or installed e.g.
dev-util/android-sdk-update-manager-20.0.3
dev-java/icedtea-bin-7.2.2.1-r1
dev-java/icedtea-bin-6.1.11.3-r

In manuals you will find the rest:

http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Portage

http://wiki.sabayon.org/index.php?title=En:HOWTO:_The_Complete_Portage_Guide

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it but `PORTAGE_OVERLAY="" emerge world -unD` should work.